# Online status для пользователя Django

Tags: django

Здравствуйте.
Есть необходимость понимать, какие пользователи в данный момент онлайн на сайте.

Один из вариантов, это использовать `is_authenticated`, но я так понимаю, что если пользователь закрыл браузер, и остался аутентифицированным, то запрос будет возвращать `True`.

Другой вариант - использовать `WebSockets`, или в частности `Channels`. Но ради простой задачи, не очень хочется использовать `Daphne`, однако, этот вариант даст на 100% то, что нужно - если пользователь закрыл браузер, то отработает `on_disconnect`, и я буду знать, что юзер сейчас оффлайн.

Интересует, как вы мониторите онлайн юзеров в Ваших приложениях.

Заранее спасибо за любую полезную информацию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть отличное решение - [django-presence](https://github.com/synw/django-presence), которое практически не требует изменений в текущем стэке.

Есть лишь одна зависимость - [Сentrifugo](https://github.com/centrifugal/centrifugo)

Всем рекомендую.

Answer (score 1):

Я протестировал [django-online](https://github.com/thoas/django-online) на своём сайте. Установлен Django 2.2.6. Всё работает из коробки. Чтобы использовать это приложение написал короткий тэг для шаблонов. Вот его код:

```
from django import template
from online_users.models import OnlineUserActivity
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def who_is_online():
    user_activity_objects = OnlineUserActivity.get_user_activities() 
    return [user.user for user in user_activity_objects]
```

Answer (score 0):

Да просто запоминаешь, когда последний раз пользователь запрос делал, и от этого времени крутишься. Можешь считать, что онлайн те, кто делал запрос не больше чем пять минут назад, можешь считать, что те кто 30 мин назад запрос делал.

В основном эту задачу решают таким способом.

Answer (score 0):

Можете посмотреть в сторону решения [django-online](https://github.com/thoas/django-online). Из минусов он работает под django 1.6, но вы можете просто переделать middleware под нужную версию django.